# Inverse search search via syncTeX

Tags: texniccenter, forward-inverse-search, sumatrapdf

I'm using TeXnicCenter 2.0 with SumatraPDF and MiKTEX2.9 and try to use the **inverse search**. I set up the profile according to the instructions / different fora but I can’t manage to get it work then using

```
\input{./folder/file.tex}
```

In the *.synctex file the link

```
Input:75:C:\mainfolder\folder\file.tex
```

shows up correctly, however, somewhere in between the file. Now, I copied the link to the end of list of inputs at the top of the synctex-file, saved it and its working fine.

Does anybody has an idea, who I could this running (automatically;-)? Is that a known bug?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on the Sumatra-Version and the description of backward and forward synchronization on http://william.famille-blum.org/software/sumatra/index.html.

I used that version and description to overcome the problems to configure syncronization of Sumatra and WinEdt. That should work with TeXnicCenter as well.

With a running configuration, it was no problem to update that specific Sumatra-Version using the latest one from the Sumatra homepage without losing the configuration settings.